# Firefox resize image differently causing gap/extra pixels between images?

Tags: javascript, css, image, firefox, cross-browser

I have a row of images that floats left, I resized the images to *height:160px* and added the width of all the images up. Then gave the parent div a width. (In my project I'm using iScroll so that's why I'm doing this).

```
img {
    height: 160px;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    display:block;
}
```

javascript:

```
var scrollerWidth = 0;
$('.scroller').find('img').each(function(){
    scrollerWidth += this.width;
});

$('.scroller').css('width', scrollerWidth);
```

Everything works fine in Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox. In FF, the last image will go to the second row. However the total width traced out to be the same as in Chrome. And you can see there's this really tiny gap between images.(it's not always visible, if you resize the browser you can see it sometimes)

you can check my jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/shibbydoo/sQGk3/10/

The reason I thought it might be due to how Firefox resize images is that if you change the *height* to 200px, then everything's fine. Does anyone know why is it doing this? Thanks.

ps. All the image width traced out to be the same in Chrome and FF, but it's obviously not the same...

Comment: I think compid is right about the rounding. Interesting note (keep this in mind for debugging): this problem goes away if you remove the line setting the width of your scroller. This means that your JS is limiting the scroller in a way that makes it cut an image off the first row

Comment: yeah I'm aware of that, unfortunately I need to set it for iScroll to work in my project (not used in jsFiddle)

Comment: Then either scale images to the sizes you want them, or specify width attributes as well. Seems like a huge pain though, because I'm guessing you'll eventually use more than four pictures. Could you put each picture in its own div, and give all the divs uniform dimensions? Then extra horizontal space would be solid black or something. It would look consistent, and make it much easier on you if/when you add to the project.

Comment: This (uniform image containers) would also make responsive design a little easier!

Comment: but wouldn't ff still round up differently when i change the height percentage on the container? and my images are not all of the same size...

Comment: They aren't the same size, so pick dimensions that can be applied to all of them. For example, give them all a max-height and a max-width, so that each picture will (presumably) fill at least one of those dimensions completely, then scale accordingly with regards to the other dimension. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/trojansdestroy/UKzXX/). Does that work for you?

Comment: thanks for the example, but this doesn't work on the design I have, I don't want to make them all the same size by adding the bg. Thanks again still, I actually found a way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to compid and trojansdestroy I was able to brainstorm think of this. Since each image width is traced out to be the same in FF and Chrome (The weirdest part), I just set the width of the image to the width that's traced out, and that fixed it.

```
$('.scroller').find('img').each(function(){
    scrollerWidth += this.width;
    $(this).css('width', this.width);
});
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shibbydoo/sQGk3/15/)

Answer (score 4):

### Cause

I believe this is due to a rounding error. When you set the height of the image to 160px and leave the width unset, you are telling the browser to set the width according to the original aspect ratio. This means the width may not be exactly an integer, but will still be rounded to the nearest integer by the browser. I suspect FFdoes the rounding slightly differently which causes an additional pixel in the total.

The most mysterious part is that both inspectors report the same widths for all the images. However, after careful inspection of a screenshot in Photoshop, it seems like Chrome renders the total image width to be 682px, while Firefox renders the total image width to be 683px (which is larger than the javascript calculated 682px).

This image:
https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYhlmIx0ZgQCMA9xmnttw4vvrZIrlZpC9QNBhN9FoBUc46DFse
renders 1px wider in FF.

### Fix

The best fix for this is proably to use images at 100% their size, instead of having the browser resize it. This reduces loading time to a minimum, and ensures you do not have issues with the rounding of image dimensions.

Comment: yeah that's the same thing I'm suspecting, but I need to change the image size in order to make my site responsive... any other possible fix? resize the image in javascript maybe?

Comment: what is the ultimate result you want to achieve?

Comment: to have the images all in one row. I found a way around last night, thanks for your help.

Comment: what was the fix, out of curiosity?